# How could I start with TFS2010 and VS2010?

Tags: tfs

I'm learning TFS2010 these days, someone said that you could create areas and iterations to begin a project, do I need  to put solutions into these areas and how to do it? Is there are any sources for VS2010+TFS2010 development? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Areas and iterations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997576.aspx) are not directly connected to solutions (I think you mean VS - solutions) as you can see in the link to MSDN.
They are the way to structuring you work.

[Here you can get started](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2009/10/21/tutorial-getting-started-with-tfs-in-vs2010.aspx) [or here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286491%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[Here](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.de/2010/02/team-foundation-server-2010-work-item.html)  you can find a TFS 2010 Work Items Basic User Guide

And [here](http://www.codefest.at/post/2011/07/01/MSDN-Videos-uber-Visual-Studio-und-Team-Foundation-Server-2010.aspx) you can find a big collection of videos of different categories.